# Horizontally interleaved layout graphics and text blocks

Tags: positioning, layout

What's a good way to make an interleaved layout having text blocks aligned to one side and images/graphics aligned to the opposite? Or in other words: Imagine a raster of a three column layout where the text spans over the left and center layout column and the images span over the center and right column.